# Custom button not showing as grey when disabled

Tags: swift

I have created a custom button, and I have set it to be greyed out when it is not Enabled. However, when I run the program, the disabled buttons are not greyed out. What could I be doing wrong.

Custom Button Class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init (frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        config()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        config()
    }

    func config(){

        // Setting disabled/enabled traits
        setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControl.State.disabled)
        setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControl.State.normal)


        if !isEnabled{
            backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }else{
            backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }

        // Other styling options
        layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // Making it look 3D
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    }

}
```

Button Initialization (also set in storyboard)

```
    @IBOutlet weak var movePickPosBut: CustomButton!
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you enable and disable the button?

Comment: `if(self.currBut == 1){
                        self.but1.isEnabled = true
                        self.but2.isEnabled = false
                        self.but3.isEnabled = false
                        self.but4.isEnabled = false
                    }`

Thank you!

Comment: And where do you run this code? Is it in `viewDidLoad`, in response to a user action, or something else? Also, have you verified that the line is actually running?

Comment: This is in a function that is called repeatedly in viewDidLoad. The line is running, because when I set the title color, it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting of the background colour according to the `isEnabled` state is static and not dynamic; that is, at button construction time you are checking if it is enabled (which it probably will be) and setting the background colour accordingly. But this is not changed when the `isEnabled` flag is changed.

Instead, use the system functions to control the background according to state. So replace this code:-

```
if !isEnabled{
    backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}else{
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

With this:-

```
self.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.gray, for: .disabled)
```

This will keep the background colour associated with the state.

You'll also need this code, which I've taken from [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/25/uibutton-background-color/) (and may provide further help).

```
extension UIButton {

  private func image(withColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fill(rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
  }

  func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {
    self.setBackgroundImage(image(withColor: color), for: state)
  }
}
```